# How to use for loop in r for generate indexes variables to calculate math function

Tags: r, loops

I would like to calculate this functions for 37 data set as follows:

The first data is V1

```
library(trend)
Q1 <- API37[,"V1"]
mk.test(Q1)
sens.slope( Q1);


The second data is V2

Q2 <- API37[,"V2"]
mk.test(Q2)
sens.slope( Q2);



.
.
.


Q37<- API37[,"V37"]
mk.test(Q37)
sens.slope( Q37);
```

How to write R code using for loop or while loop to calculate run this function for each data ?

I tried to write this but did not work.

```
for (i in 1:37) {
Q[i] <- API37[,"V[i]"]
mk.test(Q[i])
sens.slope( Q[i]);
print (Q[i])
}
```

I nee do generate results for each Vi , i=1,2,...,37 separately and print it as list

Could any one help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your expression `API37[,"V[i]"]`, the part `"V[i]"` will never be equal to `"V1"`, `"V2"`, etc., while you're incrementing your counter `i`. It's simply the character string `"V[i]"`, remaining constant at each iteration. Replacing this expression by something like `API[, paste("V", i, sep = "")]` should work.

However, there are more efficient ways to implement what you are trying to do. Posting a minimal working example would help to give you such solutions, but here is an example using a fake dataset randomly generated:

```r
library(trend)

### 1. Generate an example dataset:
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10)
colnames(dat) <- paste0("V", 1:10)
head(dat)

### 2. Perform a MK-test for each variable:
apply(dat, MARGIN = 2, mk.test)
```

You can adapt this to your dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot Philopolis for your answer.

Comment: How we schedule  the obtained results from this function ? (How export it into Table or excel) Highly appreciated

Comment: It's a really different question and it would be better to open a new topic for that. But you will have to specify what you would like to retrieve exactly (only a table of p-values, or a whole well-formatted document with the entire output for each variable).

Comment: Thank you very much